# Как узнать id получателя при отправке через socket.broadcast?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Как узнать/получить/указать id клиента при отправке ему сообщения методом socket.broadcast?

Пример кода в котором сервер переадресовывает входящее сообщение остальным клиентам.

```
socket.on('set_data', function (data) {     // обработчик входящего сообщения
    socket.broadcast.emit('set_data', {
        from: socket.id,                    // от этого клиента пришло сообщение
        to: ?,                              // этому клиенту пересылаем сообщение
        data: data
    });
});
```

UPD уточню что сообщение надо разослать всем, и Каждому отправить Его же id на сервере.

Comment: broadcast это послать всем, кроме того кто послал сообщение.

> To broadcast, simply add a `broadcast` flag to `emit` and `send` method calls. Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except for the socket that starts it.

Comment: чтобы послать сообщение конкретному юзеру надо в его socket сделать emit т.е. вы например при соединении и авторизации/идентификации пользователя делаете такое свойство объекта (connections например):


    connections[clientid].push(socket);

а потом делаете что-то вроде(когда послать надо)

   for (var i=0,l=connections[clientid].length;i<l;i++) connections[clientid][i].emit(/* .... */);

можно и не сам сокет хранить а его id, но это сути не меняет, проще все-таки ссылку на сокет, чем потом ещё как-то извращаться.

Comment: Обновил вопрос: отправить нужно всем их же id-шники

Comment: А можете показать как вы храните активных пользователей?

Answer (score 1):

Ну как я понял подобное не укладывается в логику socket.broadcast